# Creating stub for interface in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, soap, asp.net-core

I am in the process of porting existing code from .net 4.0 to .net core 2.0. The current solution is a WCF service, unit tests and a stub (for third party). The WCF service has been rewritten as a .net core RESTful API and the unit tests are being developed to work with this.

I need to be able to provide a mechanism for development environments to be able to use the new API for integration testing and these means communication between the API and another service. Historically, we have simply setup a standard website and exposed an .asmx that implements the interface;

```
public class AutoId : System.Web.Services.WebService, IIdentificationService_1_1Soap
{
}
```

Without adding an old style web application, which I can then add an .asmx to, I am not sure how I can achieve this. I am led to believe the .asmx and wcf services in the .net core world are dirty words, so how can I expose this interface (not consume it) in .net core?

Comment: "asmx" and "wcf" are not dirty words in the .NET Core world, they are just non-existing. Since neither one exists in .NET Core. I'm not sure why you have the need to expose any of the interfaces, you already have an REST Api which is reachable from outside. Or are you looking into client generation tools such as Swashbuckle Swagger (based on Swagger/OpenAPI Spec), which can be used to quickly generate clients code (for different programming languages) for integration tests?

Comment: The API needs to talk to another service, we need to expose this during development and outside of unit testing.

Comment: Can't you just use the dependency injection/environment variables built-in ASP.NET Core to change dependencies for a specific environment (Development, Staging, Production or any custom defined environment)? `appsettings.<environmentname>.json` (or environment variables) for test/prod credentials, named Configure/ConfigureSettings Startup methods for dependencies (see "Startup Conventions" section in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)

Comment: We still need something to implement that interface and expose it to the API for consuming. At present, it is an .asmx file in a standard .net 4.5 web application. I am asking what is the correct way to achieve the same in .net core.

Comment: Are in need of a url routing?